# javascript the difference between the number 01 and 1

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that needs to be able to tell the difference between the numbers 01 and 1. I am doing a cubical search within a company directory and on the same floor there are cubicles numbered 01 and 1. When the cubical search returns 01 it automatically assumes the value is a 1 and not '01'.

Is there a method or something I could use to differentiate between '01' and '1'.

Thanks.

Comment: If you treat the numbers as strings (ie: '01' !== '1') you are able to differentiate between the two!

Comment: This information is lost as soon as you convert the strings to numbers

Comment: How is `01` entered? How are you using it? There are many ways this can be wrong....

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the numbers `01` and `1`. They are absolutely identical.

```js
console.log(01 === 1);
```

There is a difference between the strings `"01"` and `"1"`. If you need to distinguish between the values, then use strings, not numbers.

```js
console.log("01" === "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method or something I could use to differentiate between '01' and '1'.

Yes, string comparison.

When you treat these two values as strings then these two values will be different

```
var isEqual = '1' === '01'; // false
```

Only by converting them to numbers will they evaluate the same and be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't really NUMBERS, they are CHARACTER STRINGS, whose characters all happen to be digits.

I presume that you are doing a "cubicle search" - a search for a cubicle (those little pens that companies keep people in), rather than some sort of mathematical search that involve cubes

Answer (score 0):

You will treat both inout as strings. Consider this:

```
var x = "01";
var y = "1";
var z;
if (x === y) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Note there is a difference between == (value only) and === (value and type)